# Вывод нескольких значений таблицы пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу вывести номера гаража (id), через запятую

Код;

```
<?
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `garage` WHERE garOwner='$login'", $link);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $result['ID']; //вывод ид гаража
    }
        ?>
```

Так как у пользователя 3 гаража, получается 505154, вместо 50,51,54 как поделить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать так, например:

```
echo $result['ID'] . ",";
```

Comment: А если выводить несколько id? <?
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `garage` WHERE garOwner='$login' DESC LIMIT 1", $link);
    while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $result['ID']; //вывод ид гаража
    }
        ?> Добавляя DESC LIMIT 1, то он же будет выводить только 1 значение, а как сделать отдельный вывод для каждого?

Comment: Не очень понял ваш вопрос. Если можно, по конкретнее опишите. DESC LIMIT 1 - вывод одного последнего значения из БД.